# Angularjs accessing var, got undefined

Tags: angularjs

```
$http({
  method: 'GET',
  withCredentials: true,
  url: 'http://...' + $scope.orderId
}).success(function(data) {
  $scope.order = data;
  $scope.products = $scope.order.items; * * $scope.shopid = $scope.order.shop_id; * *
  $scope.packagings = $scope.order.delivery.packaging_details;
  $scope.packaging_breakdown = $scope.order.delivery.packaging_breakdown.combine_packaging;
  $scope.packaging_breakdown_items = $scope.order.delivery.packaging_breakdown.combine_packaging.items;
  $scope.item_arr_length = $scope.packaging_breakdown_items.length;
  $scope.show_orderDetails = true;
  $scope.shop = $resource('http://..' + $scope.shopid).get();
}).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
  $scope.show_orderDetails = true;
  $scope.err_msg = data.error.message;
  $scope.status = status;
  console.log($scope.status);
  if ($scope.status == "400")
    document.getElementById('order_page').innerHTML = "<div class='alert-box error'><img src='images/error.png'/><span id='err_span'>error:</span>" + $scope.err_msg + "</div>";
});

var obj1_overall_experience_rating = $firebase(new Firebase("https://..." + * * $scope.shop_id * * +"/overall_experience_rating/counter1")).$asObject();
```

These two parts are in the same controller, but can't access $scope.shop_id outside of this $http, i've got undefined instead of id number

Comment: 1st thing withCredentials should be inside headers it should be like `headers: { withCredential: true }` add this to ur $http

Comment: @pankajparkar i think you are wrong, it should just be a part of config object itself. You may want to validate your understanding pehaps!! See the [official documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#usage)

Comment: @PSL that's my bad, sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like on line 8 you are saving the id value as `$scope.shopid`, but in the bottom of your code you are accessing the value using `$scope.shop_id`. Add/remove the underscore in one of your references.

By the way, it would be helpful if you formatted your code in an easier to read way. Very difficult to follow.

Edit: Also, now that the formatting is cleaned up a bit, it looks like there will still be a bug even after you fix the property naming. `$scope.shopid` will not be defined until the HTTP request gets a response. However, that last line of code will be run immediately, even before there is a response, therefor `$scope.shopid` will still be undefined during that last line of code, even once the naming is fixed up.

This should work:

```
var obj1_overall_experience_rating;

$http({
  method: 'GET',
  withCredentials: true,
  url: 'http://...' + $scope.orderId
}).success(function(data) {
  // data parsing
  $scope.shopid = $scope.order.shop_id;
  // more data parsing
  setExpRating($scope.shopid);
}).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
  // error handling
});

// this could be made even more modular using an angular service
function setExpRating(shopid) {
  var connection = new Firebase("https://..." + shopid +"/overall_experience_rating/counter1");
  overall_experience_rating = $firebase(connection).$asObject();
}
```

What I did here was change all references of `$scope.shop_id` to `$scope.shopid`, and also added a function for handling the Firebase connection, which is invoked only once a response is received from the initial HTTP request.

I would also recommend taking that one step further and creating a service or two for handling the Firebase connections and experience rating calculation. The controller is doing too much, which is likely one reason you got a handful of bugs. Trying making small, modular services that the controller relies on - it will make your angular code much easier to work with.

Comment: thanks for your explanation and finally i got it because of your help :)